# Building cost when fast building

Tags: warcraft-3

When fast building a building with human, how much does it cost to fast build per worker?

I know that every worker increases building speed by 50% but how much more does it cost per worker?

Answer (score 3):

1 gold and 1 wood every second for every additional worker.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from the [liquipedia wiki](https://liquipedia.net/warcraft/Peasant)

```
Powerbuild Cost :   0.15
Powerbuild Rate :   0.6
Repair Cost Ratio   :   0.35
Repair Time Ratio   :   1.5
```

This suggests that it costs 15% more per worker to finish a building.

So 5 workers on a town hall makes the town hall cost 60% more.

I'm going to test that soon and confirm here.